# How to .update() value to NULL in sequelize

Tags: javascript, database, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm writing my service to update a row using sequelize for PostGres. When I try out my query using a PSequel it works fine:

```
UPDATE "test_table" SET "test_col"=NULL WHERE "id"= '2'
```

But using sequelize it throws a 500 error:

```
db.TestTable.update({ testCol: NULL }, { where: { id: id } })
  .then((count) => {
    if (count) {
      return count;
    }
  });
```

My model does allowNull which I believe is what allows null values to be the default as well as set:

```
testCol: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: true,
  defaultValue: null,
  field: 'test_col'
},
```

Any other value but NULL works as expected. Is there a different method for setting null values?

Comment: strange, it seems the column structure no problem to me

Comment: where: {
    id: id 
  }

give id ad no 2 or define it

Comment: Sunil - I have done that before. Finding the correct row to update is not the problem right now as I can update it to any other value but null.

Comment: Read and act on [mcve].

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the looks of it, I think your issue is that you are using SQL's syntax for a null value ('NULL') where you should be using JS syntax ('null').

```
db.TestTable.update({ testCol: null }, { where: { id: id } })
  .then((count) => {
    if (count) {
      return count;
    }
  });
```

should work.

Comment: This works most of the time, depending on the global configuration of Sequelize you may still run into problems where it is not deleting null values.  For this scenario, you may need to add the `omitNull: false` flag to the update options.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked a more detailed error message in logs? I'd suggest you to add a promise catching error and then update your question.

For now, my guess is that you created your connection with `omitNull: true`. Call an update function with just one null property probably is the reason of error 500 because it'll generate a incomplete `UPDATE` command (without `SET`).

Try to set `omitNull: false` or, if you cannot do this test, try to update this way:

```
db.TestTable.testCol = null;
db.TestTable.save(['testCol']);
```

More info [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html).